# Creating a non-generic function for adding items to a HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, hashset

In my C# program, I want to add items to a `HashSet<T>` via reflection. With a `List<T>` this is not a problem because I can cast the list to the non-generic `IList` interface:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in myClass.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object value = property.GetValue(myClass);
    IList valueAsIList = value as IList;
    if (valueAsIList != null)
        valueAsIList.Add(item2Insert);
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing with `HashSet<T>` but there is no non-generic contract like `IList` that I could cast it to and call the `Add` method. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: A `Hashset<T>` is also an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @stuartd and Chris: OP was mentioning `IList` because `List<T>` implements the non-generic `IList` interface which can be used to add an untyped object to the collection. But `HashSet<T>` does not have such a non-generic contract it implements.

Comment: Ah, I didn't fully appreciate the question, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already are using reflection, why not try to lookup the Add method?

```
var addMethod = value.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Add");

//validate this method; has it been found? What should we do if it didnt? Maybe it should be SingleOrDefault

addMethod.Invoke(value, valueToAdd)
```

Maybe add more validations and what not.. :)

Comment: Note that `value` is the *object*, not the type, so you would have to do `value.GetType().GetMethods()…`. Also, you can use [`GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx) (singular) to get the method directly without having to query all of them.

Comment: Fixed, thanks!! About the specific GetMethod("Add") would work as well, but you have to catch the AmbiguousMatchException as well

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with `dynamic`. It will "take care of" the reflection work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bob
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hash = new HashSet<int>();
            Console.WriteLine(hash.Count);
            Add(hash);
            Console.WriteLine(hash.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Add(dynamic hash)
        {
            hash.Add(1);
        }
    }
}
```